# CORS configuration with Authorization and angular

Tags: angular, cors

I am building an app with frontend based on angular and backend on yii2. I have CORS configured for the moment inside the framework like

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        \Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE');
        \Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type');
        \Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    }
```

This configuration works for all requests, POST and GET alike which does not include Authorization header. But for the one request so far that has Authorization it says

```
Access to fetch at 'http://docker.me.com/api/users/3eea14e9a1659e8e849c806d7eff5ad6.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have tried to define `http://localhost:4200` as my Allow-Origin value, but the result is still the same.

Making a curl request to the same point I get:

```
>curl "http://docker.me.com/api/users/3eea14e9a1659e8e849c806d7eff5ad6.json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 3eea14e9a1659e8e849c806d7eff5ad6" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -D -
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 May 2020 12:37:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.5
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Debug-Tag: 5ec1302552af4
X-Debug-Duration: 372
X-Debug-Link: /debug/default/view?tag=5ec1302552af4
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=oqss701mi72l7shjjb0veoqhtm; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _identity=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _csrf=252702ff0a3553be04c75e84288b5839de461426ef2c4a13e8add9585ebac678a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22FGsZMf8ArRw10nJtc3xxj8k1naxBxdFC%22%3B%7D; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"id":47,"email":"maniakalen2@gmail.com","name":"Test","surname":"Test","photo":"/assets/images/silhouette.gif","details":"","phone":"","user_type":"consumer"}
```

where it is obvious that the response headers are set. I also tried to set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials for those who are wondering.

What am I missing in the picture here?

---

Per request I add a screenshot from the network tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. curl won't fail, because it doesn't check CORS.

According to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

> For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.

Therefore you need to put here a real origin instead of `*`.

In case of local development with `localhost:4200` it would be

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

for a prod

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-domain.com
```

The easiest way to do it is to parse request headers and use `Host` header here, but still, to respect security - please validate that it's the host you want to allow.

---

If it still fails it means there are headers, or a HTTP method used that haven't been specified in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` or `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, I would blame `Headers` and double check that it really allows all required headers.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Might you add a screenshot from the browser Network tab on the failed request that shows both request and response headers? Authorization header you can blur. Perhaps it misses some headers and methods.

Comment: Screenshot added, although I doubt it will be of a real use

Comment: Might you include response headers too?

Comment: The browser does not show the response headers properly, but I believe they are the same as in the curl request.

Comment: The problem of the curl request is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, it should be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200` and that's why I want to verify on the screenshot of the response headers to ensure all CORS headers are correctly set.